# WebGL Firefox profiler interpretation

Tags: firefox, webgl, profiler

I use Firefox profiler and it shows that call to WebGL2RenderingContext.drawArrays takes 28% of the running time ( which comes to a few seconds ), underneath there is WebGLContext::DrawArraysInstanced with the same 28% and below glDrawArraysInstanced with only 0.1%.
For this simulation my vertex and fragment shaders are simple one liners.
How can this be correctly interpreted ?

I would think it only measures the time it takes for JavaScript (CPU side) to run the command and if I measure it directly it gives me times under 1ms. Does it somehow measures how much time takes on the GPU and if so how come it takes so long for a one liner shaders ?
Why WebGLContext::DrawArraysInstanced has 28% and the only thing beneath only 0.1%?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you post a minimal repo [in the question itself](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Comment: @gman it is not an easy task, I am more interested to get answer how to interpret the results i.e. what is measured there and if it is JavaScript why it differs so much from timing I get with wrapping the call into performance.now() rather then why it happens

Comment: Well, making my own test I can't repo your results. Even with 1000 calls to `drawArrays` per frame it doesn't show up in the profiler for me. So basically without a repo I can't help. Maybe someone else can.

Comment: @gman I understand. Do you know what time is reported there: CPU or GPU ?

Comment: I am not familiar with FF's profiler. Are you using JavaScript or Emscripten or what? I don't know how to get non-JavaScript to show up. certainly wouldn't expect to se WebGLContext::DrawArrayInstanced->glDrawArrayInstanced as those are C/C++ functions but maybe you have some features turned on that I don't. Are you updating buffers often? Are you updating element arrays (indices)? Are you using vertex arrays?

Comment: As for repo, you should be able to take one of the 1000s of working examples on this site and adjust it to run whatever shader you're running that's having this issue or a similar shader with the same number of uniforms, textures, and attributes. It shouldn't be more than 20 minutes of work. If it doesn't repo the issue then add more until it does. You'll either find the issue or have a repo that will let others find the issue.

Comment: @gman I figured out what was causing dreadful performance: it was creating and allocating large textures and attaching them as render targets to a framebuffer - around 100 per frame. Now that I set them up in advance and reuse simply swapping framebuffers it is much better. But it does not answer my question. It seems to me that the profiler somehow includes other GL calls into WebGL2RenderingContext.drawArrays even though it reports them separately too.

Comment: That makes sense. That why I asked for more code. If you'd have shown the code we'd have likely told you that's the issue. Most validation in WebGL (and OpenGL) has to happen at draw time and just in general you should try to set things up as much as possible at init time, not render time.